# How to check if Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-10.0

How to check if the `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has been granted? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
  "Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
  == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

The above code always returns false, despite the permission has been granted. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Environment.isExternalStorageManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#isExternalStorageManager()).

Answer (score 2):

As [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) Said, You can use `isExternalStorageManager()`

Returns whether the calling app has All Files Access on the primary shared/external storage media.
Declaring the permission `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` isn't enough to gain the access.
To request access, use `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`.

**Example**

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if(!Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
        {
              try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                    storagePermissionRequest.launch(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    storagePermissionRequest.launch(intent);
                }
        }
    }
```

Result Contracts. [ActivityResultContracts](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts)

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> storagePermissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                            showPermissionDeniedDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I hope it will helpful to others.

Comment: what about APIs before 11

Comment: @moumenShobakey you can use requestLegacyExternalStorage and normal permissions

Comment: I am using them, but i still can't access downloads directory

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),  
                Manifest.permission. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE //Android 10, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for older
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                REQUEST_CODE. // you can use it then in onActivityResult() etc.
            )
        } else {
             doSomething() //now you have permission
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately ```checkSelfPermission ``` approach does not work. CommonsWare answered my question now. Thank you anyway!