# Programmatically Install APK on Android 12 - " Permission to access file: /storage/emulated/0/xxxx.apk is denied "

Tags: java, android, installation, package, permission-denied

With Android Studio, Java language, I write an application that install a package which APK is /eduphone/eduphone.apk
On Android 12 I get the following error on Logcat :
Permission to access file: /storage/emulated/0/Download/eduphone/eduphone.apk is denied

I tried several solutions proposed in Stak Overflow, but none works.

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.termux.permission.RUN_COMMAND"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test4"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="eu.eduphone.install.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.termux" />
        <package android:name="eu.edduphone" />
    </queries>
</manifest>`
```

Here is provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Here is the Java code for permission :

```
public void getdroits () {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if(!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()){
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES)
                        .setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Java code for the APK insttallation.
The argument passed to this code is String PATH = "/sdcard/Download/eduphone/eduphone.apk"

```
  private  void instApp(String PATH){
        Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        File file = new File(PATH);

        if(file.exists()) {

            Uri  uri ;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
            } else {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);

            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"APK "+PATH+" not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help !
Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @Commonsware is rigth.  But in my case I do not plan to publish this app on a store. This app is an installer for very few people which will want to install a specific environment on their smartphone (a Moodle server + a Nextcloud running thanks to Termux App). They will have to validate my global conditions before anything else.

That why I solve my problem by allowing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

For that :

I add in the manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

At the early beginning of my app, I check and  request permissions as seen in [How to obtain MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250814/how-to-obtain-manage-external-storage-permission) and [How to check if Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is granted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244807/how-to-check-if-manifest-permission-manage-external-storage-is-granted) :

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            //request for the permission
            Log.d("Thierry", "Request ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Then for app installation :

```
    private  void instApp(String PATH){
    Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
    Log.d("Thierry", "Install PATH : "+PATH);
    File file = new File(PATH);

    if(file.exists()) {
        Uri  uri ;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Log.d("Thierry", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES");

            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Log.d("Thierry", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES");
        }
        Log.d("Thierry", "INSTAPK  URI="+uri.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION| Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "Error in opening the file!");
        }
    }else{
        Log.d("Thierry", "INSTAPP , Not existe"+PATH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permission to access files in `Downloads/`, except for files that you place there yourself from your app.

Rather than thinking in terms of filesystem paths, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` to let the user choose the APK. Then, you can pass the `Uri` you get back into your `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` `Intent`. You need no filesystem permissions and you do not need `FileProvider` for this approach.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. My app is a global installer : it install several APK then launch commands. I'd like it to be the more automatic as possible, with the less click as possible. So asking the user to select APK is not suitable.
Do you think it is possible to : first copy the APK files into the private app storage, then install them ?

Comment: @Coilhac: "Do you think it is possible to : first copy the APK files into the private app storage, then install them ?" -- no, because you do not have permission to access files in `Downloads/`, except for files that you put there yourself.

Comment: Thanks again.  What is strange is that I can read the file system, I mean directories and file names, with "Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String shell); "  I wrote an kind of ShellExec(), and execute shell commands like df, ls, find, sed, grep, which work fine on /sdcard/  But mkdir and cp fail. 
Do you think it is possible  to include my APK files inside my App in Ressources, and find them in my private storage so that I can install them from here ?

Comment: @Coilhac: Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on your device. You could copy those resources to files (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` to them. However, please understand that everything you are describing will prevent your app from being distributed on the Play Store (and perhaps other app distribution channels) and may be illegal where you live. I **strongly** recommend that you spend time talking to a qualified attorney.

Comment: CommonsWare, your method based on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT works fine. This page was useful https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-004.html I will redact an answer with final code. Notice I don't plan to put my app on any app distribution channel. It is only an help for installing a Learning Management System Moodle server on Debian on smartphones using Termux-app, it could be useful in Africa for teacher and students who have few internet access. See https://moodlephone.org . In addition to the apps there is a tar.gz of 1.2 GB. Thank you again. Thierry